# How to put only left or right $, in formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

i Want to create a Macro that put left $ in a cell if this have a formula
but now i only can do for both, for example A2 ---> $A$2,
how can i modify my code to only chose left or right symbol?
Thanks !

This is my code

```
    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'Absolute Fomula'
Dim c As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In Selection
    If c.HasFormula = True Then
        c.Value = Application.ConvertFormula(c.Formula, xlA1, , xlAbsolute)
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the formula in a cell? What should the formula look like after you have run the macro?

Comment: in this case is a simple formula, but i'm trying to do for more complex formulas 
 =+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C13,Cap_LoB!A2:C110,3,0),"")

Comment: because my target is have a selection and do for all formulas in that selection range, but i don't know how can i put only left $

Comment: Once you run the Macro, what will the formula look like? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlreferencetype

for the alternatives to `xlAbsolute`

```
Name                Value   Description
xlAbsolute          1       Convert to absolute row and column style.
xlAbsRowRelColumn   2       Convert to absolute row and relative column style.
xlRelative          4       Convert to relative row and column style.
xlRelRowAbsColumn   3       Convert to relative row and absolute column style.
```